# Invalid App ID The Provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm building an android app as an academic project, I've added Facebook sdk to my app, and before the error message, it used to show a facebook share dialog but then this error message started to appear

> Invalid App ID: The Provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID

when I executed this code

```
ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(activity);
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) 
{
  ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
  .setQuote(msg_string)
  .build();
  shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```

At Facebook for Developers Console, my App is in "**In Development**" status, and "**Unavailable to the public**". I do not understand why it suddenly started to show the error message related to App ID. 
I'm asked for a Privacy Policy URL when I try to make the app public, facebook asks me to submit app for review, which again asks for a Privacy policy URL. 
See this snapshot of my faceboook for developers console:
[image]

I just want my app to be able to post data to facebook, and have no such specific privacy policy concern because this app is just an academic project and meant only for testing API integration with the app i'm building.

Any information or directions are appreciated. Thanks.